# WebSocket Client Error on .net core with Linux Docker image with botframework directline

Tags: docker, .net-core, botframework, direct-line-botframework

**System Information**

**SDK Language**: .NET Core 1.1.2

**Development Environment**: Docker - Linux container

**Issue Description**

Hi, I connect to the botframework directline channel with websocket. My client is build with .net core and running in Linux container.
I have the following issue:
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The same code works well when it runs on windows.

Thanks for your help !

**Code Example**

System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket client = new System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket();
await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/XXXX"));

**Actual Results**

System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)

Comment: Does this sample work for you? https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLineWebSockets. Just trying to figure out if there is something specific on your code or not

Comment: The sample target .net full fx. I'm using .net core 1.1 on linux

Comment: I know, just wanted to make sure there isn't an issue with Direct Line itself. What happens if instead of using web sockets, you use the "pooling" flavor of DirectLine. do you have issues too?

Comment: My code works well on Windows, so it doesnt seem to come from directline...  may be the .net core implementation of ClientWebSocket...

Comment: But the code you are showing is incomplete, right? I mean, where are you getting the auth token to create new conversation and thus get the stream url?

Comment: Yes and no. I got the StreamUrl from the .net DirectLineClient with  
var conversation = await directLineClient.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();
the value into conversation.StreamUrl is valid, I can connect  and try with https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. My complete code works well in windows, but not in Linux !!!

Comment: Currently BotBuilder .NET SDK does not support .NET Core. For more info, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/572

Comment: @NilsW I know, my issue is not related to the botbuilder sdk, and I don't use it... I'm just using the websocket furnished by the directline rest api.
My issue seems to be related to the SSL certificate used by *.botframework.com